# How to toggle animation of the collapse icon in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a custom Font Awesome icon for the collapsed navbar in Bootstrap 4, and I'm trying to make it rotate on click. I managed to do it for the first click, but after that no matter how many times I click the animations don't trigger.

Here's the HTML for the navbar part:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

        <button id="toggler-btn" class="navbar-toggler btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span id="clpse-icon" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

And these are the CSS animations:

```
.fa-arrow-down-animated {
    animation-name: collapse-icon-animation;
    animation-duration: 0.15s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

.fa-arrow-up-animated {
    animation-name: collapse-icon-animation-reverse;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes collapse-icon-animation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

@keyframes collapse-icon-animation-reverse {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

And finally this is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#toggler-btn').on('click', function(){
        if($('#toggler-btn').attr('aria-expanded')){
            $('#clpse-icon').removeClass("fa-arrow-up-animated").addClass("fa-arrow-down-animated");
        }

        else{
            $('#clpse-icon').removeClass("fa-arrow-down-animated").addClass("fa-arrow-up-animated");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm still a beginner so I hope you would explain with as much detail as you can about why this doesn't work. When I inspect the icon I can see that the classes are not being added/removed after the first click, even though the jquery code should activate on each click.
And sorry in advance if this is a repeated question but I've been looking for hours for a similar issue and have not found one.

Comment: The value of attributes are all strings.  String 'true' and string 'false' are both truthy

Comment: `$('#toggler-btn').attr('aria-expanded') === 'true'` should be the conditional

Comment: Oh, that explains why when I added an else if statement with a `!$('#toggler-btn').attr('aria-expanded')` it always executed the else if statement only. Anyway A. Meshu provided me an easy way to do this with toggleClass without even if statements, but thanks your comments were helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `toggleClass()` instead. Just add to `span id="clpse-icon"` the classs: `fa-arrow-down-animated` so it will be:

```
<span id="clpse-icon" class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-arrow-down-animated"></span>
```

And your `JS` can be something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggler-btn').on('click', function(){  
      $('#clpse-icon').toggleClass( "fa-arrow-up-animated" );
    });
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggler-btn').on('click', function(){  
      $('#clpse-icon').toggleClass( "fa-arrow-up-animated" );
    });
});
```

```css
.fa-arrow-down-animated {
    animation-name: collapse-icon-animation;
    animation-duration: 0.15s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

.fa-arrow-up-animated {
    animation-name: collapse-icon-animation-reverse;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes collapse-icon-animation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

@keyframes collapse-icon-animation-reverse {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button id="toggler-btn" class="navbar-toggler btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span id="clpse-icon" class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-arrow-down-animated"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can learn about the `toggleClass` from [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). Enjoy Code!

Comment: @ajjsiraj did you check my answer?

Comment: This works beautifully.
jQuery has so many easy helpful methods, if only I knew the right ones to use at the right time.

Comment: Yea I just checked your answer and implemented your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ajjsiraj no problem. (: